# jsf 2.0 spring 3 scope request not working

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I am trying to use spring to provide managed beans to jsf.  I assume that @ManagedBean will be picked up by JSF container to link the EL in JSF to managed bean even when I use spring by configuring spring usage in faces-config.xml.

Spring shall provide the beans but now **who manages scope of the beans?**

I have tried following annotation on beans to have it become Request scope but they do not work.

```
@ManagedBean(name="helloBean") //meant for JSF
@RequestScoped //meant for JSF
@Scope(value="request") //meant for spring
@Controller //meant for spring
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {
```

Actually earlier I was using plain JSF and @ManagedBean and @RequestScoped were working well.  Now as I tried to integrate using spring the scope are not working.

I have even tried setting bean scope in spring config but they work as expected in context of spring (singleton and prototype) but not web request context.

I was trying to avoid having to use above @Scope and @Controller annotation hoping that JSF will manage scope but do not seem like.

Below are my files snippet for spring config and MyHelloBean which probably will help communicate better.

```
<bean id="helloBean" class="com.mkyong.common.HelloBean" init-method="init" />

<bean id="myHelloBean" class="com.mkyong.common.MyHelloBean" init-method="init" >
        <property name="helloBean" ref="helloBean"></property>
</bean>

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@Scope(value="request")
@Controller
public class MyHelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //@ManagedProperty(value = "#{helloBean}")
    private HelloBean helloBean;
```

see in above MyHelloBean I am using spring DI to set helloBean which gets set by spring fine.  I have commented out @ManagedBean which I think I can leave it in there as it will be ignored by spring any ways and JSF is not going to process it I guess but to be safe I commented it out for JSF to not process it.

To complete I use below in faces-config to activate spring usage.

```
<el-resolver> 
org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver 
</el-resolver>
```

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is a bit confusing in the sense that it seems that you're mixing Spring XML configuration and Spring [Annotation-based](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) configuration. As described as an example [here](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2007/12/19/annotate-jsf-beans-with-spring-25/), if you're using annotated configuration then you should have:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcom.package" />
```

to order Spring scan for the annotations. Otherwise, if you're using XML configuration then you should have:

```
<bean id="helloBean" class="com.mkyong.common.HelloBean" init-method="init" scope="request" />
```

as by default the `scope` for a Spring bean is `singleton`.

Comment: You absolutely right.  I was able to add the scope=request to spring config and keep my plain old jsf beans with their annotations and it works as expected.  I was confused with annotation and scope on spring side.  Other reply shares some more ideas on scope and injection but I feel for me this one is simpler and easy migration towards integrating spring into jsf.  I knew only two scopes for spring beans.  where are these other scopes listed ? The spring-web (context loader) understand these new scopes and so they make sense in spring-web context ? or they valid for core spring too I doubt?

Comment: [Spring Bean scope reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Answer (score 5):

Our team faced similar problems integrating JSF and Spring beans, including problems with their scopes. And here I am to share our knowledge.

## Scopes

Basically now, when you defined in your application context, that **Spring will be managing your beans, thus scopes**. Spring will map JSF scope annotations to his native scope annotations.

- Example when both Spring and JSF support provided scope:

@RequestScoped annotation will be mapped to @Scope("request") Spring's annotation, etc with other supported scopes.

- Example when Spring does not support JSF's provided scope:

@ViewScoped is not defined in Spring's native scope annotations, thus (not sure) it will use Spring's default scope, which is singleton, or request scope (not sure).

## Bean Injection

In JSF2 you used @ManagedProperty annotations for injection, while Spring uses @Autowired annotation. **What are the differences and which to choose?**

- Injecting Spring beans with @ManagedProperty:

Spring component you wish to inject must have a value which will match jsf injection annotation's value: @Component(value = "valueMatches") injected with @ManagedProperty(value = "valueMatches").

- Injecting Spring beans with @Autowired:

Spring component you wish to inject must does not require a custom value to distinguish, if it is the only implementation of the bean you are injecting: @Component injected with @Autowired.

## Our way

We used Spring's annotations for defining Beans, Scopes and Injection.

We marked JSF beans with @Scope(value = "desiredScope"), @Controller(value = "beanName") and @Qualifier(value = "beanName") annotations. Later which could be accessed from JSF context with help of  in faces-config.xml via "beanName" value defined in the @Controller annotation.

We marked Spring services with @Service annotation.

We injected Spring services and JSF beans with @Autowired annotation.

We found ViewScope and FlashScope custom implemetations on the web and used them for our beans. Thus we did not lose any of JSF2 scopes and even added new one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I guess I need to read some spring web (spring mvc ?) related notes to understand these new annotation inject, service, component, qualifier.  I prefer getting away without using them and just use scope="request" in bean config as pointed out by other reply.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine. In our case it was just, that we needed JSF's ViewScope, but our application was based on Spring beans, so this was better for us. Just be aware of possible issues with Spring and JSF2 noted here, especially if you are going to inject Spring Components and use States which supported by JSF, but are not supported by Spring.

Comment: @JMelnik can you share your FlashScope code? I am having a hard time finding it online

Comment: @Andre sorry, cant find it. Try searching something like 'spring flash scope'.

Comment: @JMelnik i've been doing that for a while now with no luck. Apparently Spring 3.1 implements the flash scope, but I can't get it to play nice with jsf (Primefaces 3.2). Thanks though